# taphold in jquery mobile freezes

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using the taphold event in jquery on dynamic cretated list items.

```
showList(){
  var ul = $('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></u>');                        

  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
     var li = $('<li class="listItem"></li>');
     var link = $('<a href="javascript:doSomething()"><img src="images/folder.png" class="ui-li-icon" /><h2>' + i + '</h2></a>');
     li.append(link);
  }                     

  $('#myDiv').append(ul).trigger('create');

  $(".listItem").on( "taphold", function(e){
     alert('taphold');
  });
}
```

The event is fireing and I can see the alert. But after that jquery mobile freezes. I can not click or scroll.

On a motorola defy with android 2.3.7 it works like a charm, on a motorola moto g with android 4.4.2 it freezes.

Everything is hosted in a phonegap app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the alert().

When I remove the alert it works on all testes devices.